# how to load different number of string element in every row by numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dataset like that (0:5 row) ,every row have different number of elements, like 2,3...

```
whole milk,margarine
yogurt,brown bread,coffee
pork,yogurt,coffee
bottled water,bottled beer
whole milk
salty snack
```

I have tried

```
gro_arr = np.genfromtxt("groceries.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=",")
```

but it shows the

```
Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 3 columns instead of 4)
    Line #3 (got 1 columns instead of 4)
    Line #6 (got 5 columns instead of 4)
    Line #7 (got 1 columns instead of 4)
```

how to solve it?

Comment: You can't do this using `.genfromtxt` and numpy isn't really meant for non-numeric types so it's got no real use here even if you tweaked your data so it was a proper 2D structure... What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Is there other way to save this dataset, because I want to calculate the number of element in every row and find the max, min,and avg, for example, the first row is 2, 2nd row is 3, 5th row is 1

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to work with the frequency of word occurrences?

Comment: @JonClements yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You can read in the lines in **two different ways**:

1. Split each line into the number of contents in that line.
2. Store the contents of the lines post-splitting into a padded-numpy-array.

I have made a class with necessary methods to do this in a few lines. So, you could apply it as-is, without making hardly any changes to it.

### Example

```py
s = """whole milk,margarine
yogurt,brown bread,coffee
pork,yogurt,coffee
bottled water,bottled beer
whole milk
salty snack
"""

tc = TextToColumns(file = 'source.txt', 
                   sep = ',', 
                   text2columns = True, 
                   savedata = False, 
                   usedummydata = True, 
                   dummydata = s)
tc.make_dummydata()
tc.toarray()
```

**Output**:

```sh
array([['whole milk', 'margarine', ''],
       ['yogurt', 'brown bread', 'coffee'],
       ['pork', 'yogurt', 'coffee'],
       ['bottled water', 'bottled beer', ''],
       ['whole milk', '', ''],
       ['salty snack', '', '']], dtype='<U13')
```

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import os

class TextToColumns(object):
    """Reads in text data and converts text into 
    columns using user specified separator.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file: path to the file
    sep: (str) separator. Default: ","
    text2columns: (bool) if True, adds empty strings as a padding to create a 
                         2D array. Default: True
    savedata: (bool) if True, saves the data read-in after splitting with the 
                     separator, as a part of the object. Default: False
    usedummydata: (bool) if True, uses dummy data to write to a file.
                         Default: False
    dummydata: (str) the string to use as dummy data.
                         Default: ''

    Example:
    # test-data
    s = '''whole milk,margarine
    yogurt,brown bread,coffee
    pork,yogurt,coffee
    bottled water,bottled beer
    whole milk
    salty snack
    '''
    # Text-to-column transformation 
    tc = TextToColumns(filename = 'source.txt', 
                       sep = ',', 
                       text2columns = True, 
                       savedata = False, 
                       usedummydata = True, 
                       dummydata = s)
    tc.make_dummydata()
    tc.toarray() 
    # Uncomment next line to clear any dummy data created
    # tc.clear_dummydata() 
    """
    def __init__(self, file, 
                 sep: str = ',', 
                 text2columns: bool = True, 
                 savedata: bool = False, 
                 usedummydata: bool = False, 
                 dummydata: str=''):
        self.file = file # 'source.txt'
        self.sep = sep
        self.text2columns = text2columns
        self.savedata = savedata
        self.usedummydata = usedummydata
        self.dummydata = dummydata

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TextToColumns object"

    def make_dummydata(self, dummydata=''):
        """Save a string as a file to use as dummy data.
        """
        s = """whole milk,margarine
            yogurt,brown bread,coffee
            pork,yogurt,coffee
            bottled water,bottled beer
            whole milk
            salty snack
            """ 
        if (self.dummydata == ''):
            self.dummydata = s       
        if (dummydata == ''):
            dummydata = self.dummydata        

            with open(self.file, 'w') as f:
                f.write(dummydata)

    def clear_dummydata(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.file):
            os.remove(self.file)            

    def readlines(self):
        return self.toarray()        

    def read_file(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.file):
            with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            return lines
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid file path.')

    def split_lines(self, lines=None):
        data = []
        self._max_length = 0
        if lines is None:
            lines = self.read_file()
        for line in lines:
            linedata = [e.strip() for e in line.split(sep)]
            length = len(linedata)
            if (length > self._max_length): 
                self._max_length = length
            #print(linedata)
            if length > 0:
                data.append(linedata)
        if self.savedata:
            self.data = data
        return data

    def toarray(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = self.split_lines()
        padded_data = []
        if self.text2columns:
            for line in data:
                padded_data.append(line + ['']*(max_length - len(line)))
            if self.savedata:
                self.padded_data = padded_data
            return np.array(padded_data)
        else:
            return data
```

Comment: @4daJKong Please consider **`voting up`**.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the`csv` file using `open` and then read each line and `split` it by the comma delimiter.

```
allLines = []

with open("groceries.csv", 'r') as f:
    while(True):
        line = f.readline()[:-1] # [:-1] to avoid the \n at the end of the line
        if not line:
            break

        line = line.split(",")
        allLines.append(line)

for l in allLines:
    print(l)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['whole milk', 'margarine']
['yogurt', 'brown bread', 'coffee']
['pork', 'yogurt', 'coffee']
['bottled water', 'bottled beer']
['whole milk']
['salty snac']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there other way to save this dataset, because I want to calculate the number of element in every row and find the max, min,and avg